# connecting with facebook in iphone

Tags: iphone, facebook

how to connecting with facebook in iphone or I need all benifit of facebook in iphone 
I try  code but I Get only login to face book & logout from facebook

AND
 if some one help me to get API Test Console from face book I can done this facebook connection to iphone  please help me out

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iphone+facebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is just for 'share with your friends' type of integration then also take a look at [ShareKit](http://www.getsharekit.com/) ...